# Spark DataFrame InsertIntoJDBC - TableAlreadyExists Exception

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, singlestore

Using Spark 1.4.0, I am trying to insert data from a Spark DataFrame into a MemSQL database (which should be exactly like interacting with a MySQL database) using insertIntoJdbc().  However I keep getting a Runtime TableAlreadyExists exception.

First I create the MemSQL table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, val INT);
```

Then I create a simple dataframe in Spark and try to insert into MemSQL like this:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Array(123,234)).toDF.toDF("val")
//df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [val: int]

df.insertIntoJDBC("jdbc:mysql://172.17.01:3306/test?user=root", "table1", false)

java.lang.RuntimeException: Table table1 already exists.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This solution applies to general JDBC connections, although the answer by @wayne is probably a better solution for memSQL specifically.

insertIntoJdbc seems to have been deprecated as of 1.4.0, and using it actually calls write.jdbc().

write() returns a DataFrameWriter object.  If you want to append data to your table you will have to change the save mode of the object to `"append"`.

Another issue with the example in the question above is the DataFrame schema didn't match the schema of the target table.

The code below gives a working example from the Spark shell.  I am using `spark-shell --driver-class-path mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar` to start my spark-shell session.

```
import java.util.Properties

val prop = new Properties() 
prop.put("user", "root")
prop.put("password", "")  

val df = sc.parallelize(Array((1,234), (2,1233))).toDF.toDF("id", "val")   
val dfWriter = df.write.mode("append") 

dfWriter.jdbc("jdbc:mysql://172.17.01:3306/test", "table1", prop)
```

Comment: Hi Elbow, I am using spark 1.5 and I am still getting table already exists exception even after saying write.mode("append") do you like to comment  on this ?There is already an object named 'customer_spark' in the database

Comment: Hey @DJElbow, same here, still getting the  "Table 'table1' already exists" exception. when write.mode(SaveMode.Append). I checked and when using 'root' user, it's working great, but when using a user with CREATE/INSERT/UPDATE privileges, I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 3):

The insertIntoJDBC docs are actually incorrect; they say that the table must already exist, but in fact if it does, it'll throw an error, as you can see above:

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/03cca5dce2cd7618b5c0e33163efb8502415b06e/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.scala#L264

We recommend using our MemSQL Spark connector, which you can find here:

https://github.com/memsql/memsql-spark-connector

If you include that library and import com.memsql.spark.connector._ in your code, you can use df.saveToMemSQL(...) to save your DataFrame to MemSQL.  You can find documentation for our connector here:

http://memsql.github.io/memsql-spark-connector/latest/api/#com.memsql.spark.connector.DataFrameFunctions

Comment: Very nice.  That simplifies things.  Is there a compiled jar available for download somewhere?  Having  trouble finding one.

Comment: If you add maven.memsql.com as a resolver, you can include it as dependency in your project:

https://github.com/memsql/memsql-spark-connector#using

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue . Updating spark version to 1.6.2 worked fine